# Unsung Hero Badges

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer

It says Zero Score Accepted Answers more than 10 and at least quarter of the total.

How is the count of Zero Score Accepted Answers taken?

LATEST EDIT: Are answers to own questions also taken into account?

Is it the number of answers that get accepted before it is voted up/down?

OR

Is it the number of answers that get accepted and don't receive votes until a certain amount of time after the answer was accepted?

If neither of these then how? Please clarify.

Just academic interest.

Comment: I think the first one, not sure.

Comment: I think you're looking for this:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Unsung Hero

- gold; awarded once; same family as Tenacious (silver)
- Have more than ten accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 25% of all your accepted answers

  - Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
  - Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations
- Source: [How long do Tireless and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tireless-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded), a SO team member who checked the source code [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/284001#284001)

Courtesy: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)

Answer (score 0):

Far as I can tell, it seems to be number of answers that are accepted and simply have zero score (at all, presumably until the badge is awarded), with the 25% being "of total *accepted* answers" rather than "of total answers".

I could be wrong, but that's how it looks to me after looking down the profile of one of the few people who have this badge.

Comment: Ok. So, by you, the badge is awarded, at the moment it is found that 25% of the accepted answers are zero-score answers and the badge sticks with the awardee no matter whether later all the awardee's answers get voted up/down?

Comment: I *think* that's how it works...? I don't know for sure, but I would assume that the badge sticks with the profile once it's been awarded. The example I saw of someone with the badge, he had many answers, 32 of which were accepted overall, 10 of those being "accepted and zero-score". So I can only assume it was awarded once he broke 10. 

Ofc someone else could confirm or refute this, it's just my hunch as to how it might work.